# Laravel: Get current Controller (processing the request) in View?

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

**Question:**

How to get the "current `Controller`" in a view, that is "Processing" the Request respectively triggering/calling the View. (Beside passing an instance to the view via parameter)?

Is there some "current global Context" similar to `Request` that I can get like Controller::instance() or similiar?

Comment: I realized after i posted that answer that you actually wanted the controller instance, sorry about that. Looking at the dispatcher is seems like the instance is never assigned anywhere...

Comment: @RDelorier, your answer was really close. What version of Laravel were you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

From the Application

```
$controller = app(\Illuminate\Routing\Route::class)->controller;
```

And also, there is a nicer way

```
$controller = request()->route()->controller;
```

> Tested on Laravel 7.29.3